# C++ : 2-D Pointer Array Sorting: Selection Sort doesn't work for certain instance

Tags: c++, sorting, multidimensional-array, selection

The following code sorts one column of a two dimensional pointer array:

```
void sort(int** rowReferences, int rowCount, int colCount, int sortColumn) {
    int pos, lower, temp;

    for (int p = 0; p < rowCount; p++)
    {
        pos = p;
        lower = rowReferences[p][sortColumn];
        for (int j = p + 1; j < rowCount; j++) {
            if (rowReferences[j][sortColumn] < lower) {
                pos = j;
                lower = rowReferences[j][sortColumn];
            }

        temp = rowReferences[p][sortColumn];
        rowReferences[p][sortColumn] = rowReferences[pos][sortColumn];
        rowReferences[pos][sortColumn] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

It works in most instances, but it doesn't go quite right with a certain column.

The column values are in this order: 2 , 0 , -1 , 1 , 3

The sort function returns this order after displaying: -1 , 0 , 2 , 1 , 3

As you can see, the sorting works for the first two values, but breaks down after that. How can I modify the selection sort to work in this instance?

Edit*
Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example generously provided by PaulMcKenzie: http://ideone.com/lXHFHE

Comment: And you haven't debugged this yourself using these 5 values?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling this method with rowCount = 5?

Comment: You should have provided a [mcve], like [this example](http://ideone.com/lXHFHE)

Comment: Row count is most definitely 5 when calling. The table with this array displays just fine passing the same arguments as the sorting function to the display function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code

```
 temp = rowReferences[p][sortColumn];
 rowReferences[p][sortColumn] = rowReferences[pos][sortColumn];
 rowReferences[pos][sortColumn] = temp;
```

must be outside of for scope :)

Final code:

```
void sort(int** rowReferences, int rowCount, int colCount, int sortColumn) {
    int pos, lower, temp;

    for (int p = 0; p < rowCount; p++)
    {
        pos = p;
        lower = rowReferences[p][sortColumn];
        for (int j = p + 1; j < rowCount; j++) {
            if (rowReferences[j][sortColumn] < lower) {
                pos = j;
                lower = rowReferences[j][sortColumn];
            }
        }
        temp = rowReferences[p][sortColumn];
        rowReferences[p][sortColumn] = rowReferences[pos][sortColumn];
        rowReferences[pos][sortColumn] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I completely glossed over that so many times and was just looking at the variables for an error. Thanks much!